# Second monitor displays an underscore 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, monitor

I have a GTX 950 connected to a huge monitor (via HDMI) which works fine, and a second monitor (18" Dell) connected via VGA which displays things fine during boot (and in Windows), but by the time I hit the Ubuntu splash screen, it is just a blank console-like screen with only an underscore displayed in the top left. I am using the NVIDIA binary driver (361.42).

I have tried Detecting Display in System Settings and in Nvidia's XServer program to no avail. I have tried rebooting, re-plugging, etc.

Not really sure how in the world to solve this! Would really appreciate some help

/edit for googlers: I fiddled with xserver and display settings for days to no avail. I had to buy a VGA-DVI adapter ($10) and plug the secondary monitor into the DVI port on my graphics card.